# Populating achartengine graph from database

Tags: android, database, achartengine

I've been researching this and not finding much out there--probably because it's very simple. I'm trying to populate a bar chart in agraphengine from a cursor that I have. I have confirmed that the cursor pulls back 30 rows (expected), but I don't know where to go from there.

Here is my array that I'm populating:

```
    public static List<double[]> getChartData(int iDays){
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

//cursor returns expected 30 results

```
    Cursor graphData = db.query(CS_Table, new String [] {"count(*)-1"}, null, null, "strftime('%Y-%m-%d',  " + Time + ")", "strftime('%Y-%m-%d', " + CS_Drink_Time + ") BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date('now','-" + iDays + " day')) and strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')", Time , null); 

    for(graphData.moveToFirst(); graphData.moveToNext(); graphData.isAfterLast()) {
        values.add(new double[] {graphData.getInt(0)});
        graphData.moveToNext();
        }

    graphData.close();
    return values;  
}
```

And here is what is calling the function--from achartengine:

```
 public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "total" };
   List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>(DBhelper.getChartData(30));
values.addAll(DBhelper.getChartData(30));   
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE};
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Drinks in the past " + DBhelper.getChartData(30) + " days", "Date", DBhelper.CS_YDrinks, 0,
        /*y axis*/32, 0, /*x axis*/10, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    // renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    // renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
        Type.STACKED);
```

The symptom is that it seems to only pull the first number from the array list as it will only plot one bar. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You are using buildBarDataset in a strange way, I guess you have taken it from the examples? It looks like you have modified it? In what way? My guess is that the buildBarDataset returns multiple dataSet with each of the values in each. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a corresponding value to match each bar in your string and color arrays. You are probably seeing only one blue bar with the title "total".